# How to optimize pagination on a SELECT DISTINCT sql?

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-batch

My query is a select distinct on a very large database, and in pgAdmin sql tool the query itself lasts 12 sec.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (city, airport, zip, country, name) city, airport, price, id FROM mytable;
```

The spring-batch reader definition:

```
JpaPagingItemReader<MyEntity> reader;
reader.setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE);
```

If I define the `PAGE_SIZE` to be as large as the database columns, the performance is equal to 12 sec.
But if I set the size to a lower value (eg pagesize = 100.000 on a 1.000.000 datarows db), the performance is very bad (~ 10x as long).

Spring-batch applies specific pagination on the queries in the background. What is does:

```
query.setFirstResult();
query.setMaxResult();
```

if page size is 10, den the queries executed are as follows:

```
    firstResult, maxResult
    0, 10
   10, 10
   20, 10
   30, 10...
```

This again translates to `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in SQL.

Question: is a `SELECT DISTINCT ON` not combinable with pagination LIMIT/OFFSET? To me it seems as if the full select distinct query is executed again on each "pagination" run, and thus lasts very long.

So, if the database must anyhow make a full distinct select before applying the maxresults, can I temporary save the "distinct" select and just fetch the next page?

How can I improve this, without having to set the pagination size to 1million. Or is improvement not possible here?

Comment: Use a query analyzer to see what is going on, if there are columns in there without indexes you might run into trouble.

Comment: I'm having an index on `city, airport, zip, country, name`.

Comment: As mentioned use the pgadmin tool to analyze the execution of the query (paged and unpaged) and see what is happening and what is taking so much time. Also this is mentioned in the postgresql guide *"The rows skipped by an OFFSET clause still have to be computed inside the server; therefore a large OFFSET might be inefficient."*

Comment: OK I see that the costs for a `SELECT DISTINCT ON(..) * FROM..` are great, but `.. ON(..) city FROM..` has bad performance. Must I therefore place an index as a combination of rows that are selected? I tried putting an index on the selected columns `city, airport, price, id` but that did not change anything in the costs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using multiple threads to process this, an alternative would be to use the `JdbcCusorItemReader`.  That way you wouldn't need to optimize the paging aspect of the query at all.  If you're using multiple threads, this isn't an option.